# Linker errors (LNK2001) with Boost library (filesystem.hpp) in CLI/CLR code

Tags: boost, linker, lnk2001

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days and can't seem to find a solution. I am creating a Windows Forms application inside of MSVS 2012 (but the application itself is using MSVS 2010 binaries and .NET 4.0). The application requires the use of CLI/CLR managed code.

I have followed the [Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) guide and built the libraries using:

```
bootstrap.bat
.\b2.exe --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete
```

I setup/linked the directories to my project inside of Visual Studio:

- C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories > "C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Boost"
- Linker > General > Additional Library Directories > "C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Boost\stage\lib"

Here is all that I added to my previously compiling and executing code:

```
#define BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC                 //show diagnostics
#define BOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H                  
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED       //don't use deprecated code
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;
```

Here is the output of the build (Release/Win32):

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PROJECT_NAME (Visual Studio 2010), Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  PROJECT_NAME.cpp
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_53.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_53.lib
1>PROEJCT_NAME.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __clrcall boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@$$FYMABVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>PROJECT_NAME.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __clrcall boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@$$FYMABVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>PROJECT_NAME.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __clrcall boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int> const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@$$FYMXPB_W0AAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$codecvt@_WDH@5@@Z)
1>PROJECT_NAME.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int> const & __clrcall boost::filesystem::path::codecvt(void)" (?codecvt@path@filesystem@boost@@$$FSMABV?$codecvt@_WDH@std@@XZ)
1>PROJECT_NAME.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_code __clrcall boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void * &)" (?dir_itr_close@detail@filesystem@boost@@$$FYM?AVerror_code@system@3@AAPAX@Z)
1>C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PROJECT_NAME\Release\PROJECT_NAME.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Do I still not have something built/linked correctly? Let me know if there's more information needed and I will supply what I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviving an old post, I know, but I spent a long time trying to figure out a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091713/application-exiting-on-launch), so I'm posting for the next person who comes across similar issues.

For this to work, you'll need to build Boost with VS2012 or download it from [Teeks99](http://boost.teeks99.com/) or [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.55.0/). I was unable to make it work with VS2010.
Change the Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2012 (v110) in the Project configuration properties. That worked for me when I was trying to figure out a similar problem (`#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` in a VS2010 minimal example code). Make sure that the Common Language Runtime Support is set to `/clr` (NOT `/clr:pure`).